# Multiple artists modelling the same file

Tags: workflow

I am looking for a workflow that allows multiple artists to work on a project where users can work in parallel and assuming they don't change exactly the same thing the work can be smoothly merged.

I am used to working with a game engine using xml and many separate binary files which works well with a versioning system like git or svn.

Comment: *"assuming they don't change exactly the same thing"*? There are alot of other things to factor in. Possible duplicates of [Does Blender support any form of collaborative editing?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/671/does-blender-support-any-form-of-collaborative-editing) and [Does Blender have a file locking feature?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/672/does-blender-have-a-file-locking-feature)