# How can multiple people work on the same file?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I can't find any new answers to this question. I was just wondering if there is any way that multiple people can work on the same project? I don't mean at the same time. An example of what I am talking about is with the Unreal Engine, there is something called Perforce I think and it when one person is done working on it, they update it on their end, and the next person can "checkout" the file and it updates the changes the other guy did.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7378/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/671/599

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly there is no built in way to do this. So far the popular method has been to use [git](https://git-scm.com/) or [svn](https://subversion.apache.org/) which, while not built for this, can be made to work. (although keeping track of who uses what file is a complicated, I personally use a google sheet, but people forget to update it)

The down side with git and svn is that they can require some technical knowledge, such as command line usage. There are GUI apps ([Github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/),[Source Tree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)) that help; however I always find myself having to resort to using the command line.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but it seems possible to use git for binary files since the beginning of this month: https://github.com/blog/2069-git-large-file-storage-v1-0.